# How to add a database table content to combo box items in C# using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I want to make a combobox read its items from a table in a database. How should I write the code in Entity Framework v6.x?

Comment: Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Really weak question. It is easily searchable

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to know how to read data from a database using EF or how to populate combo box items? Or both? Also, it is not clear whether are you using a web, Winforms, WPF, or another technology? I guess you can split these 2 tasks and have 2 functions:

1. Obtaining the items from the database(read about DbContext class)

```
private List<MyItems> GetItems()
{
    List<MyItems> items = dbContext.Items.ToList();
    return items;
}
```

2. Populating the combo box function

```
private void PopulateComboBox(List<MyItems> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```